# Error 0x8007003B copying large files to DFS share

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, dfs

Here is the configuration.  Private network and domain (`foo.bar`).  2 file servers running 2K8R2 (`file1.foo.bar` and `file2.foo.bar`).  Created a share on each server (`\\file1\share and \\file2\share`).  Setup DFS on the domain and created a namespace (`\\foo.bar`).  Created a folder (`dfsshare`) in DFS with 2 targets (`\\file1\share` and `\\file2\share`).  Created the replication group and everything works except...

During testing (Win 7 SP1 x64 client) if I copy a large file (230MB) to the DFS share (`\\foo.bar\dfsshare`) I get the following error:

```
Error 0x8007003B: An unexpected network error occured.
```

If I copy the same file directly to one of the file servers (`\\file1\share`) I don't get the error and the file replicates to the other file server and shows up in the DFS share.  No error when copying small files to the DFS share.

I found `hotfix 983620` http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983620 but that hotfix was included in SP1 for Windows 7.

UPDATE:  Narrowed it down to ~41MB file size.  Above that and I get the error.  Below that and it works fine.  Also, network is a LAN (no routers between me and the servers) running 1000Base T.

UPDATE2:  Also verified that Windows XP SP3 machines work fine so this is limited to the Windows 7 SP1 boxes.

UPDATE3: Configured the same way on our dev network and it works.  Move the workstation to an OU that blocks all the DISA GPOs and it was still broke.  Turned off DFS replication and it works.  Turned DFS replication back on and it continued to work (very confused at this point).  Put the workstation back in the proper OU and it broke again.  This means it must be one of the DISA settings being applied by the GPOs.  Moved the workstation back to the blocking OU and it remains broke until I turn off replication.

UPDATE4:  Going through all the GPOs and we found out which one it was.  It's a GPO that sets up 802.1x which seams very strange.  We started googling DFS replication and 802.1x and found the real culprit.  Not sure how the interaction of the 802.1x and the real culprit causes the problem (maybe someone can answer that).  Anyway, if someone else answers with the correct culprit, or better yet, can explain why the interaction to the 802.1x GPO would cause the problem, I'll award the rep.  After the bounty is expired I'll put the answer in here.

SOLUTION:  It turns out the problem was McAfee on the workstation.  We had do disable "scan network drives".  Once we did this everything worked.  This error only occurs when you have 802.1x configured and the DFS share is set to replicate.  We now have an exception from security since the network shares are being scanned on the server.  There were no errors in the windows logs or on the ePO server.

Comment: Can you please clarify if you are able to always copy files of any size to both direct server name based paths \\file1\share and \\file2\share but fail when copying the same file to the DFS based path \\foo.bar\foo.bar\dfsshare?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  When copying the large file to the dfs share it fails.  When copying the same file to the file server share (file1\share or file2\share) it works fine.  hmmmm....wait.  After thinking about it I only copied the file to file1.  I'll verify tomorrow that it also works to file2.  Not sure if that matters but I'll verify.

Comment: Please check if these fixes make a difference http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968429 . Else please report if you already have them. Off to sleep so will check your response later.

Comment: Yes check file2 because we dont know where the DFS referral was pointing to yet based on what you reported so far.

Comment: Confirmed.  File copies to file2 without error.  I checked the list of fixes and none apply to this situation.

Comment: The fixes may not explicitly state that they fix your behaviour. But personally I'd ensure the NIC drivers are up to date and the fixes are installed. I think its time for you to raise a case with Microsoft support. Depends on how serious the issue is as you could keep troubleshooting...

Comment: Can you try uploading a 42MB file to the dfs while running a wireshark packet cap on the three involved interfaces (eg LAN IF on file1, file2 & the w7 desktop). Then upload the caps clearly labelled somewhere and link them here and I'll have a closer look.

Comment: @fenix - this may be a problem because the system is DoD classified and I won't be able to get the wireshark output on the Internet.  But that does give me an idea.  We have an unclassified test network so I'll look at creating a couple virtual file servers, setup DFS, and see if the problem exists there.  That would at least rule out DISA security settings and if the problem does exist there I can upload wireshark outputs.

Comment: Don't know how much to thank you for this. I was struggling with this problem for months.
McAfee was the problem (McAfee gateway AV). Once I put the exclusion in place, I can copy files over VPN, between Linux and Server 2008, back and forth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question in the hopes it will help others.  It turns out that the combination of having 802.1x configured (through GPO) and having McAfee ePO configured to scan network drives when uploading large files to a DFS share that is also being replicated will cause this error.  Not sure if McAfee knows but we are trying to open a ticket with them.  We got around this by disabling the scan network drives setting in ePO and this was ok with security because we have McAfee on the file servers.

Comment: Running Windows 10 with Bitdefender Total Security 2015 Firewall enabled will cause this error code 0x8007003B for large files transferred to a mapped drive, on my ReadyNAS, a 3GB will do it.
Solution:
Turn off Bitdefender Total Security 2015 use Windows Firewall.

Comment: I ran into the same issue using a Windows 10 1903 without any additional security installed.Disabling the default real time protection did not solve it.
Checking the windows event log, I could find a System warning `Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection Network link is disconnected.`. Possibly a network related problem or driver.

Comment: Ended up being my network driver. Windows 10 update loves to break it. (Just uninstall it in device manager and search for devices, will reinstall)